# Call Stack available to Logging Format

Tags: python, logging, format

So, I have a method that returns a simple string of the call-stack.

```
def call_stack():
    if "inspect" not in globals().keys():
        import inspect
    stack = [frame[3] for frame in inspect.stack() if frame[3] not in [inspect.stack()[0][3],"<module>"]]
    s = ""
    for method in stack: 
        if len(s) > 0:
            s += "." 
        s += method
    return s

def modify_logger(logger):
    logger.args["call_stack"] = call_stack()
```

Is it possible to create this behavior?

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(call_stack)s -- %(levelname)s:  %(message)s")

def bar():
    logging.debug("test")

def foo():
    bar()

def monkey():
    foo()

# modify root logger.
modify_logger(logging.getLogger())

# write to the log.
monkey()
```

Which results in the following entry:

```
monkey.foo.bar -- DEBUG: test
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the easiest way is just to define a custom `debug` function:

```
import logging

def call_stack():
    if "inspect" not in globals().keys():
        import inspect
    stack = [frame[3] for frame in inspect.stack()
             if frame[3] not in [inspect.stack()[0][3],"<module>"]]
    s='.'.join(reversed(stack))
    return s

def debug(message):
    logging.debug('{s} -- DEBUG: {m}'.format(
        s=call_stack()[:-len('debug.')],m=message))

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format="%(message)s")

def bar():
    debug("test")

def foo():
    bar()

def monkey():
    foo()

monkey()
```

yields

```
monkey.foo.bar -- DEBUG: test
```

Answer (score 1):

After having researched this pattern quite a bit yesterday, I realized that what I wanted wasn't reasonable for the Python language.  Its an interpreted language, after all, which means that there is always a file that exists on a known path and a line number which can be referenced.  It *would* make sense, in a compiled language like C#, Java, C, or C++ because you have namespaces, objects, and methods without the benefit of having a file/path and line number.

**Moral of the story**

When people tell you that what you're asking for doesn't make sense, don't just write them off.  Take a few moments and scrutinize your original request along with your perspective before vigorously pursuing an answer to a question that might not make sense in your specific use-case or context.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your solution mixed with another, it gave me the results I was looking for.

```
    import logging
    DEBUG = True
    TRACE = True

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # TRACE BACK
    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    class ContextFilter(logging.Filter):
        def filter(self, record):
            import traceback
            if "inspect" not in globals().keys():
                import inspect
            stack = [frame[3] for frame in inspect.stack()
            if frame[3] not in [inspect.stack()[0][3],"<module>"]]
            record.stack ='.'.join(reversed(stack))
            return True

    #-----------------------------------------------------------------------        ---------
    # LOGGER
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    logger = logging.getLogger()
    if TRACE:
        logger.addFilter(ContextFilter())

    if DEBUG:
        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(stack)s\n{%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} - %(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        fh = logging.FileHandler('log_filename.txt')
        fh.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        fh.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(fh)

        ch = logging.StreamHandler()
        ch.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
        ch.setFormatter(formatter)
        logger.addHandler(ch)

    else:
        logger.setLevel(logging.NOTSET)
        print 'NOT IN DEBUG MODE: Logging.NOTSET'
```